# What is a source for Richard Riley's famous quote about preparing students for the future?

Tags: citations, quotation

A famous quote by Richard Riley, former US Secretary of Education, is as follows:

> We are currently preparing students for jobs that don’t yet exist, using technologies that haven’t been invented, in order to solve problems we don’t even know are problems yet.

I have seen this quoted in hundreds of places, but never a full reference. I'd like to use this quote in an article that must adhere to APA referencing - does anyone know of the first place this quote appears?

Comment: See footnote 1 in [this essay](http://www.jstor.org/stable/27784366) (pp. 351-52) where the quote is thought rather to be credited to Karl Fisch (whose video does, indeed, appear to be the earliest instance of the quote I can find). It's not that Riley couldn't have said it. The content of [this article](http://www.jstor.org/stable/43311510) from 1995/6 comes close.

Answer (score 5):

*Generation Jobless* by Peter Vogel has this quote at [the beginning of Chapter 3](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1057/9781137375940_3), and attributes it to "Gunderson et al, 2004"

Checking this book's [bibliography](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/bbm%3A978-1-137-37594-0%2F1.pdf), we can find that "Gunderson et al, 2004" refers to

Gunderson, S., Jones, R. & Scanland, K. 2004. The Jobs Revolution: Changing How
America Works. Copywriters Inc

I would suggest you check there.

Answer (score 5):

With the help of Darren Ong's answer and Google Books, I found the quote in *The Jobs Revolution*, phrased as follows:

> Former Secretary of Education Richard Riley recently noted that none of the 
>   top ten jobs that will exist in 2010 exist today and that these jobs will 
>   employ technology that hasn’t yet been invented to solve problems we 
>   haven’t yet imagined.

An identical sentence occurs in *Hearing on careers for the 21st century; the importance of education and worker training for small business*, p. 90, freely available on [archive.org](https://archive.org/details/gov.gpo.fdsys.CHRG-108hhrg94136). Unfortunately, neither source gives a reference, and the quotation is not given verbatim.